# Waf distcheck not working when with variant builds and/or no Install/Uninstall steps exist

Tags: waf

Consider the following `wscript`:

- removed `install` or `uninstall` commands
- no `build` command , but `build_debug` and `build_release` commands as we are using a variant build.

```py
import waflib
from waflib.Build import BuildContext, CleanContext, InstallContext, UninstallContext

APPNAME = 'TestApp'
VERSION = '1.0.0'

for x in 'debug release'.split():
    for y in (BuildContext, CleanContext):
        name = y.__name__.replace('Context','').lower()
        class tmp(y):
            cmd = name + '_' + x
            variant = x

def options(opt):
    mctx = waflib.Context.classes
    mctx.remove(waflib.Build.InstallContext)
    mctx.remove(waflib.Build.UninstallContext)

def configure(conf):
    conf.setenv('debug')
    conf.setenv('release')

def build(bld):
    if not bld.variant:
        bld.fatal('call "waf build_debug" or "waf build_release", and try "waf --help"')
```

It is not possible to run `distcheck` on this `wscript`:

```
D:\dev\distcheck>python waf configure distcheck
Setting top to                           : D:\dev\distcheck
Setting out to                           : D:\dev\distcheck\build
'configure' finished successfully (0.007s)
New archive created: TestApp-1.0.0.tar.bz2 (sha256='290babcef54fd88ab30b46662f62fe680dc1280ae26a931f2cda3b87382cafe2')
Setting top to                           : D:\dev\distcheck\TestApp-1.0.0
Setting out to                           : D:\dev\distcheck\TestApp-1.0.0\build
'configure' finished successfully (0.062s)
Waf: Entering directory `D:\dev\distcheck\TestApp-1.0.0\build'
call "waf build_debug" or "waf build_release", and try "waf --help"
distcheck failed with code 1
```

I tried to configure the `distcheck-args` but this does not help:

```
D:\dev\distcheck>python waf configure --distcheck-args=configure,build_debug,build_debug
Setting top to                           : D:\dev\distcheck
Setting out to                           : D:\dev\distcheck\build
'configure' finished successfully (0.064s)

D:\dev\distcheck>python waf distcheck
New archive created: TestApp-1.0.0.tar.bz2 (sha256='4bf28bc95577749b25dc1cc911f4545b8c06c9fb8bac0c9ba53134bf620d0162')
Setting top to                           : D:\dev\distcheck\TestApp-1.0.0
Setting out to                           : D:\dev\distcheck\TestApp-1.0.0\build
'configure' finished successfully (0.017s)
Waf: Entering directory `D:\dev\distcheck\TestApp-1.0.0\build'
call "waf build_debug" or "waf build_release", and try "waf --help"
distcheck failed with code 1
```

This leaves two questions to me:

- How are the distcheck arguments properly overwritten, that are generated by `Scripting.DistCheck.make_distcheck_cmd`?
- How is the check generated by `Scripting.DistCheck.check` of the command output properly overwritten? There is no install dir as there is no install command.

My temporary solution to monkey patch the functions `Scripting.DistCheck.make_distcheck_cmd` and `Scripting.DistCheck.check` is not very comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you need to create a distcheck_debug and a distcheck_release with the correct variant set, as you do for Build and Clean context. Or a distcheck command only for release variant.

Comment: I have not tested it.